# Insert data to database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm using this code to insert image into database but  some error keep popping

Code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST ['insert_post']))
    {
        $product_title=$_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat=$_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_brand=$_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_price=$_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc=$_POST['product_desc'];
        $product_keyword=$_POST['product_keyword'];
        $product_img=$_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_img_tmp=$_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];   
    }

    echo $insert_product="insert into products 
        (product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keyword) values
        ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_img','$product_keyword')";
?>
```

Comment: why this e is separate in "product_imag   e"?

Comment: what is the error? You even not give command to save data to sql yet.

Comment: echo $insert_product >> where is the command at save db?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `product_image` columns datatype `BLOB` , `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`. and then get file data using `file_get_contents()` function.

```
$product_img_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']);
```

and store it in your database.